# High MySQL throughput

Tags: mysql

On a big server with many user and website from 11AM - 00AM our MySQL throughput realised in max (60 - 80M)
this timestamp our customer website load slowing .

We haven't any Disk IO , and server HDD : 6 * 600 G SAS 15K + 64 G RAM

MySQL config :

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8192M (2 G above mysqltuner recommendation)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Any idea to solve this problem?

---

**This comment add after first answer :**

Hello Dear Damiano :
Thank you so much your answer . about your comment :
I will attach the complete screen from server monitor . (end of this comment)

about slow query :
I have done this , but every 24 hrs we have under 500 slow query . and most them not occur repeatedly .

an other thing , this server big and we have High traffic web site on it , so I can not ask customer don't use server resource .

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 11573    |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 27291504 |
| Qcache_hits             | 83817933 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 36512628 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 15633028 |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 4338965  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 29930    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 106130   |
+-------------------------+----------+
```

---

**Here You are all thing need :
http://www.4shared.com/zip/jX54_Dprba/data.html**

1 screen shot + 1txt file from output server

Comment: Unfortunately the screenshot you provided is unreadable (too low resolution). Please post a better one. Also please post an updated "show status" telling us how much time passed between the two run.

Answer (score 2):

From the graph you provided (*that I'm reporting below, for the convenience of other readers*), I saw you're running [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) to monitor your server.

As such, it would help to have a look also to other graphs (like CPU, Memory, I/O and, even more important, network-traffic) that unfortunately where not included in your question.

Anyway, the *munin mysql throughput plugin* (that generate the graph below) describe itself as: "*mysql_bytes - Plugin to monitor the number of bytes sent from and received by mysql*"

So based on the graph, we saw that your MySQL is serving content to the underlying network at a speed ranging from 40MBps (Mega Bytes per second) to 70/80MBps.

Should this **not** be normal in your particular case, than, in addition to give a look to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/383896/251104), you can check/monitor what's going on on your server, searching for high-traffic query results.

As a first step, I suggest:

- **[show processlist](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html)**: to see which users are connected and which query are they running on which DB, running for how much time (should they be "long");
- enable "[slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html)": to see which queries are requiring lots of time (and, hence, might impact your performances while, at the same time, having high changes to be optimized);

Should this not be enough to get a figure on what is going on, you can:

- enable "[general log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html)": please note that this will cause a **write-log for every query run by your mysql instance**. This might seriously impact your performance so... use it wisely.

As a first guess, I think you are running under two conditions:

1. a small number of queries, returning very large recordsets, executed relatively few times (...so to generate 40/80MB of traffic) (*eg.: a single recordset made by 100.000 records, each of 300 bytes, counts for up to 30MB of traffic. So two of them, per second, can... answer your problem*).
2. a sligher higher number of queries, returning relatively small recordsets, but executed very frequently (...so to generate 40/80MB of traffic as well) (*eg: a single recordset made by 10 records, each of 1000 bytes, counts for up to  1MB of traffic when executed 100 times per second*).

The slow-query-log will help you catching the first issue. The general-log is the only one helping in the second case.

Also:

- if you are **NOT** experiencing any issues in terms of storage-I/O, than everything is happening in RAM and... mysql surely cached all the recordsets. In such a case [show status](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-status-and-maintenance.html) will help you figuring out what's going on.

Should you provide further details, we might be more helpful.

*P.S.: I'm not a mysql-performance-tuner at all so don't blame me for all the (more important) tuning issues I've surely missed :-)*

---

[image]

Comment: edite question after fist answer ...

Comment: comment Update with provide screen attach.

Comment: As I am using [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) to monitor the server for real-time queries and it also has the option to monitor the general logs and slow logs by clicking a button which in-turn fires sql commands to the server saving me time to write sql statements to do the same. It now also monitors real-time queries with performance schema support that enables us to monitor short-lived queries also. This is life-saver I would say.